# How to calculate sum of specific column based on more than 2 complex conditions in python dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, machine-learning

'So basically what I wanted to figure out is that is there a way of calculating 'batsman_runs'(not visible in the image but yes there is a column) per 'match_id' for different 'batsman' and then store them as a dictionary or a list or just print the value.
The following link is a snapshot of the dataset
https://i.stack.imgur.com/zVWSh.jpg

Comment: Show us what you've tried so far

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have imported numpy:

```
result=pd.your_df['batsman_runs'].to_numpy()/pd.your_df['match_id'].to_numpy()
```

`result` will be a numpy array, which holds all the values of the 'batsman_runs' column divided by all the respective values of the 'match_id' column.

Comment: Your snapshot finally loaded; so you want to divide by the 'match_id' column, but only have one value for each batsman? If so, you could first make a copy of the dataframe and then iterate through it, deleting all rows with a batsman you have already seen before and then run the code above on that abridged dataframe.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something  like this as you said you have a column called batsman_runs

df = df.groupby(by=['match_id','batsman'])['batsman_runs'].sum()